# GRUNT + LESS + BROWSERSYNC running on XAMPP

Tags: wordpress, gruntjs, xampp, less, browser-sync

I have a little big problem with **BrowserSync version for Grunt**.

**PROBLEM:**
If I edit .php files - BrowserSync work good but if I edited .less files, nothing happened but in bash I can still see:

> [BS] File changed: d:\localhost\htdocs\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\MYPROJECTNAME\css\main.css

Can somebody please help me to setup correctly:
GRUNT + LESS + BrowserSync running on XAMPP (because of WordPress)?

My gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        // Watch task config
        watch: {
            less: {
                files: ['less/**/*.less'],
                tasks: ['less']
            }
        },
        // less task config
        less: {
            dev: {
                files: {
                    "/localhost/htdocs/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/MYPROJECTNAME/css/main.css" // destination
                    :
                    "less/main.less" // source file
                }
            }
        },
        // Using the BrowserSync Proxy for your existing website url.        
        browserSync : {
            dev : {
                bsFiles : {
                    src : [
                    '/localhost/htdocs/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/MYPROJECTNAME/**/*.php',
                    '/localhost/htdocs/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/MYPROJECTNAME/images/*.*', 
                    '/localhost/htdocs/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/MYPROJECTNAME/_dev/less/**/*.less', 
                    '/localhost/htdocs/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/MYPROJECTNAME/**/*.css', 
                    ]
                },
                options : {
                    watchTask: true,
                    debugInfoě: true,
                    logConnections: true,
                    notify: true,
                    proxy: "localhost/www/wordpress",
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browser-sync');

    // register a default task.
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['less', 'browserSync', 'watch']);
};
```

Thanks all! :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Here is my setting

**var root = 'localhost/htdocs/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/MYPROJECTNAME/';**

```
  browserSync : {
        dev : {
            options : {
                files: [root+'style.css',
                        root+'js/**/*.js',
                        root+'**/*.php'],
                watchTask: true,
                debugInfoe: true,
                logConnections: true,
                notify: true,
                proxy: "localhost/www/wordpress",
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I will test them out, are your settings working fine